# Problem with Deriving work done by gravitational force and gravitational potential energy from the first principles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work, integration

Suppose we have a system with Two point masses of mass $M$ and mass $m$. And we want to derive Work done. Lets say M is fixed or $M>>m$. Initially assume mass m is at rest at a distance of $a$ from $M$ and after some time it reaches $b$. And we want to calculate work done. Since magnitude of Gravitational Force is $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ and displacement of $m$ is towards the big mass so Force and dissplacement are in same direction so work done should we positive. But if we calculate $\int_a^b F\cos(\theta) \,dx$ you get a different answer its negative. Since $b<a$ (Gravity is a repulsive force and after some time distance decreases between masses final distance is b and initial is a by definition) and gravitational force is just $\int_a^b \frac{GMm}{r^2} \,dr$. This has to be right because both displacement and Force are in same direction so Force multiplied by dr is as I showed above. Now when you calculate this integral you get $GMm(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b})$ which is clearly negative. What am I doing wrong. If you continue with this working to calculate potential energy you get it as positive which is also wrong. whats the mistake. The same reasoning I did for spring force and other phenonmenon its correct but gravity something wrong is happening what is it.

Comment: $b < a$ is confusing. Maybe make it $r_1$ and $r_2$, with $r_1 < r_2$. It would make your reasoning easier to follow.

Comment: Your integral is simply bounded incorrectly. The integral from b to a is the negative of the integral from a to b. It's convention to have the lower bound less than the upper bound. This would fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to look at what is going on is that when you do an integral like
$$
\int_a^b f(r) dr
$$
with $a>b$, then $dr$ is *negative*. More precisely, if you convert this integral into a Riemann sum,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N f(r_i) \Delta r
$$
with $r_1=a>r_N=b$, then $\Delta r=\frac{b-a}{N}<0$.

So let's go back to how we would do the dot product to get to the integral for work. To do this carefully, we need a vector expression for the force (not just the magnitude). We introduce a unit vector $\hat{e}_r$ that points radially outward. Then
$$
\vec{F} = -\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{e}_r
$$
since the force points radially inward.

Now we come to the displacement vector -- this is the tricky part. What you would *like* to say is that the displacement is radially inward, so that
$$
d\vec{r} = -\hat{e}_r dr \ \ \ {\rm (WRONG)}
$$
However, this **is wrong**, because:

- We know $-\hat{e}_r$ points radially inward
- We know that $dr$ is negative, by the argument above.
- Therefore, combining the above two points, $-\hat{e}_r dr$ points radially *outward*, but we know that the actual displacement $d\vec{r}$ must point radially *inward*.

Therefore, the correct equation here is
$$
d\vec{r} = {\color{red} +} \hat{e}_r dr
$$
With this substituion, we get
\begin{eqnarray}
W = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = - (\hat{e}_r \cdot \hat{e}_r) \int_a^b \frac{GMm}{r^2} dr = {\color{red}-}  \int_a^b \frac{GMm}{r^2} dr = GMm \left(\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}\right) > 0
\end{eqnarray}
as expected.

Another way to say this, which is perhaps less error prone, is that the displacement is
$$
d\vec{r} = \hat{e}_r |dr|
$$
You can avoid having to worry about the sign, if you remember that $|dr|$ means you should always choose the limits of integration to go from the smaller $r$ value to the larger $r$ value, so that $dr>0$ and $|dr|=dr$.